# $y_i \left[ 1 - \log \frac{t_i}{y_i} - \sum_{j=1}^C y_j \log \frac{t_j}{y_j}\right] = t_i \iff y_j=t_j \ \forall \ j=1,2,...,C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, information-theory

I'm trying to prove the following affirmation:

Given the constants $t_j \in (0,1)$ and the variables $y_j \in(0,1)$, for $j=1,2,...,C$:
\begin{equation}
    y_i \left[ 1 - \log \frac{t_i}{y_i} - \sum_{j=1}^C y_j \log \frac{t_j}{y_j}\right] = t_i \iff y_j=t_j \ \forall \ j=1,2,...,C
\end{equation}

I've made some simulations for differents values of $C$ and in all of them this is true, but I'd like to formally prove it or find a specific case in which the affirmation is false.

Thanks in advance to the community.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalently, you have:
$$1 - \log\dfrac{t_1}{y_1} - \dfrac{t_1}{y_1} = 1 - \log\dfrac{t_2}{y_2} - \dfrac{t_2}{y_2}=\dots 1 - \log\dfrac{t_C}{y_C} - \dfrac{t_C}{y_C}  = \sum_{j=1}^C y_j\log\dfrac{t_j}{y_j}.$$

Since the function $f(x) = \log x + x$ is increasing and thus injective when $x>0,$ it must follow that $t_i = ay_i$ for some $a>0$ for all $i.$ Then your equation becomes:
$$1-\log a - a = \log a(y_1+y_2+\dots +y_C).$$ If $a = 1$, we are done since we are trying prove that. If $0<a<1$ or  $a = 1-x,\, 0<x<1$ then:
$$1-\log a - a = x-\log(1-x) >0 ,$$
easily seen from first derivative test or the Taylor series. This would imply $y_1+y_2+\dots +y_c = \dfrac{1-\log a - a}{\log a} < 0,$ which is absurd. Similarly, if $a>1:$,
$$y_1+y_2+\dots +y_c = \dfrac{1-\log a - a}{\log a} < \dfrac{1-a}{\log a} < 0.$$

Therefore, the only possibility is $a=1$ and thus $t_i = y_i.$

Answer (score 1):

Calling $x_i = t_i/y_i$ we get

$$1-\log(x_i)-x_i = \sum_j y_j \log(x_j) $$

Because the RHS does not depend on $i$, and $f(x)=1-\log(x)-x$ is one to one, this implies $x_i=x$ is a constant.

Hence

$$ 1-\log(x)-x = \log(x) \sum y_j \implies 1 - a \log(x) -x = 0$$

with $a=1+\sum y_i >0$. Now, the function $1 - a \log(x) -x$ is continuous and decreasing on $(0,+\infty)$, hence the trivial root $x=1$ is the only one.

Hence $t_i=y_i$